# How to mention class name in namespaced scope in php

Tags: php, namespaces

I want to declare class name in another class in different namespace . I want to know what is the best method to do that ?

Currently I am doing it like

```
class RowsetAbstract implements \SeekableIterator, \Countable, \ArrayAccess
{
  protected $_rowClass = '\libDb\Table\Row\RowAbstract';
 ...
```

Actually I want to know if there is any way by which I can mention class name without giving absolute namespace.

Comment: [Why do you need it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @PeeHaa .. I want declare default class name in case no other class is mentioned .. Can I do that without mentioning namespace so that I can keep the code as library which can be use anywhere .. irrespective of path

Comment: But why do you need that? What are you trying to do in specific?

Comment: Maybe there's something you haven't thought of that will make you go "DUH, why am I even trying to do this". Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @PeeHaa I am trying to create the library that can be used in different projects and I don't to get restricted to particular namespace and folder name .Sorry this is the first time I am trying to do something like this .. so this might seems silly but I just want to know what is the best practise for this ?

Comment: Why do you need the `_rowClass` in there to begin with? What does it solve / what do you gain by having that?

Comment: @PeeHaa . actually it will not be possible for me to put whole related code over here but what I can explain over here is at one point of code I am checking a variable if it is instance of this particular class .. or null ..If it is null then I will initiate it . Can there be better way to do this ?

Comment: Yes inject whatever you need into the thing.

Comment: @PeeHaa .. so do you suggest to keep the things as they are ?

Comment: Impossible to answer with the provided info and I doubt anybody can help you. Sure I could provide a technically working solution for you, but I have the feeling I cannot provide any meaningful proper solution with the provided information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91476/discussion-between-alwayslearn-and-peehaa).

Comment: Feel free to come in the [php chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) btw